# how to do custom shipping charges for each product with zone?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, zone, shipping-method

I want to make 2 custom fields in woocommerce product > shipping tab

1. eec zone shipping cost.
2. non eec zone shipping cost

in checkout, cart page, billing, email, I want to access this cost. and manipulate with a product.

i tried "woocommerce_product_options_shipping" action make custom field in 
product > shipping tab but unable to fetch and process further as I am new to this woocommerce system.. Please suggest.

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_shipping','create_custom_field');
```

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: i used per-product plugin.and it worked !!.